# functions accessing wrong variables in eval_tidy

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

So I can't for the life of me understand what is going on here. This was supposed to be a small exploration of a possible edge case, but it wound up revealing how little I understand R/tidy evaluation.

I want to understand why, when a function is coded to access a variable it doesn't define in its arguments, `eval_tidy` can't seem to mask the variables it uses.

Consider the following, where `f` accesses a variable named `sup` that isn't passed in as an argument

```r
library(rlang) # I'm using rlang 0.3.0

# Define `sup` globally
sup <- "yes"

f <- function() {
  # Access whatever the `sup` variable is
  if (sup == "yes") "YES"
  else "NO"
}

f()
# 'YES'

q <- quote(f())
eval_tidy(q, c(sup="no"))
# 'YES'
```

I've tried just about everything, but I can't seem to mask `sup` from `f()`.

Comment: Functions are lexically scoped in R. They inherit the environment in which they are created. Here `f` is defined in the global environment so variables will be looked up there. You'd have to change the environment associated with `f`. You can't do that by changing the calling environment. This isn't going to work. Maybe check out: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping

Comment: Darn. Is this similar to what's referred to as the "enclosing" environment here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs ?

Comment: Yes. That’s the enclosing environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data masking operates on expressions, `quote(f())` in your example. However the masking is lexical, not dynamic. This means that the functions called from the expression won't be able to see the masked bindings.

There's a way to achieve what you want. You can add the masking bindings in an environment inheriting from the function's original environment, and replace the latter with the former. rlang makes this rather easy:

```
library("rlang")

sup <- "yes"
f <- function() if (sup == "yes") "YES" else "NO"

mask <- env(get_env(f), sup = "no")
f <- set_env(f, mask)

f()
#> [1] "NO"
```

However, that seems like a rather odd design choice that might give a weird feeling to your UI/DSL.

Comment: "Weird feeling"? How so?